# Regarding automatic Push Notification

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using the Google-GCM service for pushing notifications to a mobile device & building this application in Java EE.

*I'm perfectly able to push notifications to the mobile device. And from the client-end (mobile) I'm able to receive input(string).*

*`Henceforth my conceptual question starts: When I'm receiving input from a mobile (let's say: "Hello, Server"), I'm trying to build an automated process on the server-side and in reply it will push a notification (let's say: "Hi client, I'm fine; How are you?") automatically.`*

I want to grab some idea to push the notification automatically whenever the mobile device is registered. How do I do it?

Comment: I want to grab some idea to push the notification automatically whenever the mobile device is registered;

Comment: as you are new here, i edited your question properly, from next time ask your question with all your requirements briefly, it helps user to answer in right way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All realistic implementations of GCM include a stage where an app receives a RegID, and communicates the RegID back to the server, typically via an HTTP service, typically along with some other business specific data. The server would store the RegID, associating it with other data, and later use it to send messages.

Have you implemented automated the delivery of the GCM registration ID to the server yet? If so, in the same piece of code, you might as well push a notification back. If not, do put together some. Server-side implementation would depend on your server's platform, naturally.